# NodeJS use IO threads for CPU work

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Any result in google for this question refers to guides explaining how node does asynchronous operations with one thread. That not what I'm looking for.

Let say I need to process a blob, it takes 5 minutes of CPU time to process it.

I do not want to block my main thread as this worker will become unresponsive.

I would really like to to expose an interface for the logic that does the processing work, and pass it to one of the IO threads, just like in `fs.readFile`, and be let know when the processing is done.

How would I do that?

Comment: I would recommend to write a script that does the processing and run it from your main script using child_process. This will ensure your main app will be still responding since the other script will run in another thread.

Comment: I see your point but why is it more straightforward when using fs library? Does this library also spawn another process? I think not.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think that IO operations such as readFile are not blocking main thread since the process of coping data from HDD to RAM is done independently from main thread, it's managed by os and fs doesn't spawn a new process. It's quite different from child_process. This is as much as I know :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript / Nodejs is single threaded. 
Your usecase seems to be fitting a message queue system. For example Rabbitmq

You basically end up with worker services (consumers) and task queuers.
Your task queuers will fire a message to a message bus. the message bus forwards this message to another service.

I made a very simple example on github https://github.com/holoduke/nodejs_rabbitmq_simple_example